# Index was outside the bounds of the array. using EP Plus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I have a byte stream with all the data using Ep plus i want to export the file in Excel format with password protection. But it showing error in this line:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(fileBytes.ToList());
```

My whole code:

```
    public static void SendFileBytes(HttpResponse response, byte[] fileBytes, string fileName, string mimeType)
    {
        if (response != null && fileBytes != null && fileBytes.Length > 0 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mimeType))
        {
            response.Clear();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            response.ContentType = mimeType; // "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName));
            response.Charset = "";
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);



            using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
            {

                ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("heelo");

                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(fileBytes.ToList());
                pack.Save("123");
                var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                pack.SaveAs(ms);

                ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                ms.Close();


            }
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @ikerbera its throwing Exception Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Apparently this is a [known](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/8) issue in the Epplus library.

Answer (score 0):

`LoadFromCollection` needs an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a byte array.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "AAA",
    "BBB",
    "CCC"
};

ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list , true);
```

Comment: is there any way to load byte array ?

Comment: No, because a byte array could be anything, like an image, zipfile etc.

Comment: To an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I'm notable to get it. my data is in byte [ ]. i want to send data from byte array to ep plus im not able to do it. can you please help.

Comment: The data cannot be a Byte Array but a List or a DataTable. Whatever `fileBytes` originally was, convert it to one of those somehow.